# Can this theory of dyadic rationals prove that multiplying by three is the same as summing thrice?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, proof-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

(This question arose from a discussion with [Jade Vanadium](https://mathoverflow.net/users/129878/jade-vanadium) about a theory of dyadic rationals.)

Let $T$ be the 2-sorted FOL theory with sorts $ℕ,ℚ$ and constant-symbols $0,1$ and binary function-symbols $+,·$ and binary relation-symbol $<$ and axioms stating:

- $∀k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ k{∈}ℚ \ )$, and $0,1{∈}ℕ$.
- $⟨ℚ,+⟩$ is a commutative group with identity $0$, and $ℕ$ is closed under $+$.
- $⟨ℚ,·⟩$ is a commutative monoid with identity $1$, and $ℕ$ is closed under $·$.
- $⟨ℚ,<⟩$ is a strict linear order and $0 < 1$.
- $∀x,y,z{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x < y ⇒ x+z < y+z \ )$.
- $∀x,y{∈}ℕ\ ( \ x < y ⇔ x ≠ y ∧ ∃z{∈}ℕ\ ( \ x+z = y \ ) \ )$.
- Induction (along $ℕ$) for every formula in the language $⟨ℕ,0,1,+,<⟩$.
- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x·2 = x+x \ )$.

Note that $T$ proves:

- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x·0 = 0 \ )$.
- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x·1 = x \ )$.
- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x·4 = x+x+x+x \ )$.
- $∀k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ k = 0 ∨ k = 1 ∨ k > 1 \ )$.

But $T$ is essentially no stronger than PresA (Presburger Arithmetic) for $ℕ$, since any model of PresA can be expanded to a model of $T$: Simply let $ℚ = ℕ$, and define $x·k = k·x$ to be the $k$-fold sum of $x$ for each $x{∈}ℚ$ and each standard natural $k$, and define $x·y = 0$ for each $x,y{∈}ℚ$ with $x,y$ both not standard naturals.

Let $T'$ be $T$ plus the following axioms:

- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ∃y{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x = y+y \ )$.
- $∀x,y,z{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x < y ∧ z > 0 ⇒ x·z < y·z \ )$.
- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ∃k,m{∈}ℕ\ ( \ k > 0 ∧ ( \ x·k = m ∨ x·k+m = 0 \ ) \ )$.
- Induction (along $ℕ$) for every formula in the full language $⟨ℕ,ℚ,0,1,+,·,<⟩$.

$T'$ is supposed to be a weak theory of dyadic rationals. It can prove some basic facts:

- $∀x,y{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x < y ⇒ ∃z{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x < z < y \ ) \ )$.  [$ℚ$ is dense]
- $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( x > 0 ⇒ ∃k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ x·k > 1 \ ) \ )$.  [$ℚ$ is archimedean]

I have a number of conjectures:

1. $T'$ is conservative over $T$ for arithmetical sentences (i.e. with all quantifiers restricted to $ℕ$).
2. $T'$ does not prove $∀x{∈}ℚ\ ( \ x·3 = x+x+x \ )$.
3. There is a model of $T'$ in which $k·3 ≠ k+k+k$ for some standard natural $k$.

Naturally, (3) implies (2), but I cannot even find a model that witnesses (2). Does anyone know how to tackle these conjectures?

By the way, the reason for defining $T$ is that we want to say that $T'$ is no stronger than PresA, but PresA cannot even handle sequence coding so we cannot compare them in the usual manner, and moreover PresA is complete in its language so we need to expand the language to make any conservativity claim non-trivial.

The motivation for looking at such theories $T$ and $T'$ was to see how rigid having just distributivity for doubling would make the structure, and whether we can gain any 'strength' at all by having not just naturals but also dyadic rationals. If we were to add full distributivity, we certainly get a theory that is as strong as PA, but we were curious about theories that were not 'stronger' than PresA.

Comment: Since different constant terms with the same value in the standard model my be unequal, how exactly are you defining $2$, $3$, $4$, etc.?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: 2 = (1+1). 3 = (1+1)+1. 4 = ((1+1)+1)+1. I made a mistake with the 5th axiom, sorry..